# React Native for Windows Couldn't determine Windows app config

Tags: react-native-windows

I am trying to get an existing react-native app to work with native windows but I keep getting error:

An error occurred while launching the application. Error while executing command 'c:\GIT\UWP Ports\react-native-test\node_modules.bin\react-native.cmd run-windows --logging --remote-debugging --no-packager' (error code 101)
× Couldn't get app solution information. Couldn't determine Windows app config
Please check the 'React Native: Run Windows' output channel for details (error code 1302) (error code 303)

I am following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/react-native-for-windows) and already install the prereqs. I also tried [this guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cse/2016/05/26/creating-universal-windows-apps-with-react-native/) but got a similar error. How do I fix this error? I've tried with multiple machines and different react apps and keep running into this error. I am using Windows 11.